# Making 'py36' to be the root environment

Tags: python, keras

I have installed `Python 2.7` using the installer `Anaconda 4.2.0`. But due to some new code change, I will have to use `Python 3.6`. Thus I installed it using the installer `Anaconda 4.3.1`. Now when I open the `Jupyter Notebook`, I can see 2 Conda environments - root and py36.

`Root` environment has `keras` installed but `py36` doesn't. When I try to install keras in `py36`, it gives me the following error:

```
InstallError: Install error: Error: one or more of the packages already installed depend on 'conda'
and should only be installed in the root environment: conda-env conda
These packages need to be removed before conda can proceed.
```

How do I make my `py36` to be the root environment so I can install `keras` on it and run my code?

Comment: You could install both python on 1 conda, as a virtual venv: use `conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda` , and when want to use just activate it by `activate py35` then `jupyter notebook` to open notebook, or `pip install` after activate py35 to install to that env

Comment: How do I do that? Would you happen to know a tutorial?

Comment: I use it everyday, tutorial was in this link https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html#install-a-different-version-of-python

Comment: This is extremely useful. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `virtualenv` to create a secure environment for your folder before installing that kind of multiple packages to avoid conflict with other and more than one installation.

It will help you to build a secure platform to work for you.

First of all, go to your root project folder and install,

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then run this commands to secure your folder.

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Now your root project folder is secure and you can install packages inside. Those packages do not conflict with your other project version.

Try to secure your folder and then try again.

Thanks.

Comment: The OP is using the conda ecosystem, which has its own way of making virtual environments.